# How to get all files in web directory?

Tags: c#, webclient

I am trying to get all files in a web directory. 
When I use webclient to download the content of the directory's path, it shows me something like this:

```
?Ö\ reprap.htm ì]isÛ8¶ýìü
´^ÕT\y´lyM?­W¶o¥»Ú=®vlÇTsRA"$±ÃEMRv<¿þ],$A?    S¡ä´¾Ø\°o{qqïÁBáô§Ëõ>=    \¿C"Ð±»¯N2O­Ë  Ñ= zç┼¾g£Ç½?NgçèÕ«­'ß
Câ¢Á3êM|-ì¢?ØqðpB|H`[CâÄD3×$>
```

AND MORE!!!

If I use the webclient to download the data manual with :

```
var file = wc.DownloadString(http://192.168.1.100/0:/gcodes/3D_Printer_test_04N_02LH.gcode)
```

It shows me the whole file. This is what I want to achive, but the programm don't know the names of the files in the directory.

Can somebody help me?!

EDIT!!!!

the URL: http://192.168.1.100/0:/gcodes/ shows me this:
[image]

and more

EDIT!!!

the web app is the "duet webcontrol". a webpage for a 3D-Printer.
it looks like this: 
[image]

Comment: Maybe this one helps: https://forum.unity.com/threads/c-to-list-files-from-a-given-url.173109/

Comment: This didnt work for me. I think the request from the directory is the problem but i dont now how to fix it.

Comment: Do you get the files when you use this URL in a web browser?

Comment: It looks like your issue might only be your [choice of encoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.encoding?view=netframework-4.8), though I'm not sure what happens if you are not asking it for a specific resource (instead of entire folder/directory)

Comment: with this: http://192.168.1.100/0:/gcodes/3D_Printer_test_04N_02LH.gcode i see the files data,,.  With this: http://192.168.1.100/0:/gcodes/ i see something weird

Comment: i edit the view

Comment: That clearly is not a directory of files, it is an HTML form.

Comment: but over the path http://192.168.1.100/0:/gcodes/ + Filename i receive the data

Comment: A URI is not a filesystem. You can't assume `gcodes` is a "folder" with files just becasue of that. The web server is going to serve it's content however it's routing is set up. Even if it were a "folder", and "list directory contents" was enabled on the server, DownloadStringAsync would not work for getting all files.

Comment: Do u have an idea how i can fix this?

Comment: I don't know how to solve your problem without knowing more about the web app. Does it have a page that lists files anywhere?

Comment: i edit something

Comment: I would use the browser dev tools (F12) to inspect the traffic during the load of that page. The list of gcode files might be a separate request that you can make yourself if you know how this page is doing it. Are you familiar with looking at the Network traffic?

Comment: no i dont know it

Comment: Assuming Chrome browser, press F12 to open the dev tools. Select the "Network" tab in the top menu. Refresh that web page. You will probably get a lot of items in the list but one of them might be an HTTP request to get that list of gcode files. Most likely it is an XHR or Doc request which you can select in the filter to reduce the noise. If you find it, you can probably recreate the request with c#.

Comment: Try clicking the "Go Up" button while tracing the network, it might narrow it down to exactly what you need.

Comment: i got it. with this code: http://192.168.1.47/rr_filelist?dir=0:/gcodes/ i get an json object with all names